# Ожидание во views Django

Tags: python, django

Есть вьюшка которая выполняет внутри себя код от 5 до 20 минут. Вопрос состоит в том как сделать анимацию ожидания, так как если сайт вечно в прогрузке он почему-то падает в ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое что вам нужно это убрать задачу в фон. Используйте например [celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) воркеров для её выполнения . Это делается для всех задач длинною больше 15 секунд.

Когда поставите задачу воркерам получите  какой-то идентификатор этой задачи.

Отправьте этот идентификатор в js.

Js дергает этот же апи методом get с этим идентификатором. Вы спрашиваете готовность задачи. Как только будет готова - выдаете ответ. Пока задача не готова - шлите что не готова, js дергает апи дальше в цикле.

[image: схема]

Вот нашел пример, хоть и перегружен. Можно без докера и без редиса, но принцип такой. (И картинку у них "украл")

https://habr.com/ru/companies/otus/articles/503380/

Для быстродействия нужно запилить longpolling или websocket.

Answer (score 0):

я не могу гарантировать что все получится, но я это решал так:
я использовал бутстраповскую анимацию загрузки и чатгпт написал мне js, запрщающий что либо делать на время загрузки:

```
    event.preventDefault();

    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    buttons.forEach(function(button) {
        button.disabled = true;
    });

    var spinner = document.getElementById('loadingSpinner');
    spinner.style.display = 'block';

    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    setTimeout(function() {
        form.submit();
    }, );
});
```